# Can i change the sockaddr of a connected socket or How to prepare two socket to switch

Tags: c++, sockets

at the first , my partner supply me an IP , and I communicate with this IP using socket , below is my code

```
SOCKADDR_IN target; 
target.sin_family = AF_INET; 
target.sin_port = htons (8081); 
target.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr ("192.168.0.102"); 

mThreadSocket = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP); //Create socket
if (mThreadSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    return ; 
}

//Try connecting...
if (connect(mThreadSocket, (SOCKADDR *)&target, sizeof(target)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    LogTrace( TBCAF_TRACE_LEVEL_ERROR, FWARNING"Winsock started fail." );
    return ; //Couldn't connect
}
LogTrace(TBCAF_TRACE_LEVEL_4, FYELLOW"CCloudInterface: connected.");

u_long iMode=1;
ioctlsocket(mThreadSocket,FIONBIO,&iMode);

while(true)
{
    if (!process_receive())
        continue;
    if(!process_send())
        continue;   
    // above two function both use the socket "mThreadSocket"

}
```

above code works fine , but recently my partner supply me two IP , and say when one is down ,  I can switch to another one to avoid communication loss ,  but wat should I do ?

should I open two connected socket at the beginning , and use one socket first, 
switch to another one when the first is down ?

or should I only keep one socket open , then make a function for example call ReConnect() , and in this functon change socket 's IP ?  but how to do it

any help is appreciate , thank u .

Comment: So your (client's) IP stays the same and you should connect either to server IP1 or server IP2? This will not work seamlessly. You will have a connection loss and will need to (re)connect to the other IP of the server.

Comment: You need to ask your partner what you should do.  Either approach will work, however 1) the first approach wastes a TCP connection when both IPs are online; and 2) the second approach risks a momentary loss of communication while the new connection is in progress of being made, so you can lose data/events during that time, unless the new IP provides a means of recovering any lost data after connecting to it. In regard to implementing (2), you cannot change a socket's IP once it has been set. You have to close the previous socket and create a new socket to connect to the new IP.

Comment: I see , "you cannot change a socket's IP once it has been set" , you r right